# Changing file permission in Python

Tags: python, file-permissions

I am trying to change permission of a file access:

```
os.chmod(path, mode)
```

I want to make it read-only:

```
os.chmod(path, 0444)
```

Is there any other way make a file read-only?

Comment: I have seen some like S_IRUSR..how this works???

Comment: i think its just setting a bit and so when you or them together you get 0444

Comment: @AbulHasnat. Have you got any solution .. ?

Answer (score 101):

```
os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IROTH)
```

[stat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html)

> The following flags can also be used in the mode argument of
>   os.chmod():
>
> `stat.S_ISUID` Set UID bit.
>
> `stat.S_ISGID` Set-group-ID bit. This bit has several special uses. For
>   a directory it indicates that BSD semantics is to be used for that
>   directory: files created there inherit their group ID from the
>   directory, not from the effective group ID of the creating process,
>   and directories created there will also get the S_ISGID bit set. For a
>   file that does not have the group execution bit (S_IXGRP) set, the
>   set-group-ID bit indicates mandatory file/record locking (see also
>   S_ENFMT).
>
> `stat.S_ISVTX` Sticky bit. When this bit is set on a directory it means
>   that a file in that directory can be renamed or deleted only by the
>   owner of the file, by the owner of the directory, or by a privileged
>   process.
>
> `stat.S_IRWXU` Mask for file owner permissions.
>
> `stat.S_IRUSR` Owner has read permission.
>
> `stat.S_IWUSR` Owner has write permission.
>
> `stat.S_IXUSR` Owner has execute permission.
>
> `stat.S_IRWXG` Mask for group permissions.
>
> `stat.S_IRGRP` Group has read permission.
>
> `stat.S_IWGRP` Group has write permission.
>
> `stat.S_IXGRP` Group has execute permission.
>
> `stat.S_IRWXO` Mask for permissions for others (not in group).
>
> `stat.S_IROTH` Others have read permission.
>
> `stat.S_IWOTH` Others have write permission.
>
> `stat.S_IXOTH` Others have execute permission.
>
> `stat.S_ENFMT` System V file locking enforcement. This flag is shared
>   with S_ISGID: file/record locking is enforced on files that do not
>   have the group execution bit (S_IXGRP) set.
>
> `stat.S_IREAD` Unix V7 synonym for S_IRUSR.
>
> `stat.S_IWRITE` Unix V7 synonym for S_IWUSR.
>
> `stat.S_IEXEC` Unix V7 synonym for S_IXUSR.

Comment: The constants in `stat` are just convenience human-readable sugar. `S_IRUSR` is 0400, `S_IRGRP` is 040, `S_IROTH` is 4; combining them with a bitwise OR yields 0444. You could just add them instead but in the general case, OR is correct because it will work even if there are overlapping bits (0444 OR 0444 is 0444, whereas addition would yield a different and wrong value).

Comment: Using `+` also seems to work instead of `|`. I don't know if there's a reason to use one above the other.

Comment: There's no explanation on this, you have to read the comments the comments or the link to understand it, unless you already know what stat does. Just a little explanation would make it a lot better.

Comment: @Shule `|` is more proper when combining bits from two bit masks. However, if the each mask has just a single, separate bit set like all of the constants in the answer above then `+` is equivalent.

Comment: You have to watch out wit `+` when manipulating a preexisting mode. If a mode is already set then `+` won't work but `|` will. E.g., `mode = stat.S_IWUSR + stat.S_IRUSR; ... some code ...; mode = mode + stat.S_IWUSR;` won't work but the last command will work with `|`.

Comment: Okay, so how do we set just one of these without blowing away all of the others?

Answer (score 62):

Simply include permissions integer in octal (works for both python 2 and python3):

```
os.chmod(path, 0o444)
```

Answer (score 49):

`os.chmod(path, 0444)` *is* the Python command for changing file permissions in Python 2.x. For a combined Python 2 and Python 3 solution, change `0444` to `0o444`.

You could always use Python to call the chmod command using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). I think this will only work on Linux though.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['chmod', '0444', 'path'])
```

Comment: This is not working for a file on another server. Can you please suggest for that case. Thanks

Comment: A version-agnostic way to produce an octal number would be:
    int("444", 8)
Note, however, that the other answer, which suggests using symbolic values defined in the stat module is probably cleaner.

Comment: I went the `subprocess.run(...)` route for simplicity after not being able to find a quick way to do `chmod u+x` via Python's `os.chmod`.  Maybe it's just not supported vs octal notation.

Comment: What about `os.system("chmod u+x /PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE")`

Answer (score 22):

All the current answers clobber the *non-writing* permissions: they make the file readable-but-not-executable for everybody.  Granted, this is because the initial question asked for `444` permissions -- but we can do better!

Here's a solution that leaves all the individual "read" and "execute" bits untouched.  I wrote verbose code to make it easy to understand; you can make it more terse if you like.

```
import os
import stat

def remove_write_permissions(path):
    """Remove write permissions from this path, while keeping all other permissions intact.

    Params:
        path:  The path whose permissions to alter.
    """
    NO_USER_WRITING = ~stat.S_IWUSR
    NO_GROUP_WRITING = ~stat.S_IWGRP
    NO_OTHER_WRITING = ~stat.S_IWOTH
    NO_WRITING = NO_USER_WRITING & NO_GROUP_WRITING & NO_OTHER_WRITING

    current_permissions = stat.S_IMODE(os.lstat(path).st_mode)
    os.chmod(path, current_permissions & NO_WRITING)
```

Why does this work?

As [John La Rooy pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16249655),`stat.S_IWUSR` basically means "the bitmask for the user's write permissions".  We want to set the corresponding permission bit to 0.  To do that, we need the *exact opposite* bitmask (i.e., one with a 0 in that location, and 1's everywhere else).  The `~` operator, which flips all the bits, gives us exactly that.  If we apply this to any variable via the "bitwise and" operator (`&`), it will zero out the corresponding bit.

We need to repeat this logic with the "group" and "other" permission bits, too.  Here we can save some time by just `&`'ing them all together (forming the `NO_WRITING` bit constant).

The last step is to [get the current file's permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25988623), and actually perform the bitwise-and operation.

Comment: seems like there has to be a more terse way of doing this.

Answer (score 12):

Just add 0 before the permission number: 
For example - we want to give all permissions - 777 
**Syntax: os.chmod("file_name" , permission)**

```
import os
os.chmod("file_name" , 0777)
```

**Python version 3.7 does not support this syntax. It requires '0o' prefix for octal literals - this is the comment I have got in PyCharm**

So for Python 3.7 and above, it will be

```
import os
os.chmod("file_name" , 0o777)
```

Answer (score 6):

FYI here is a function to convert a permission string with 9 characters (e.g. 'rwsr-x-wt') to a mask that can be used with `os.chmod()`.

```
def perm2mask(p):
        
    assert len(p) == 9, 'Bad permission length'
    assert all(p[k] in 'rw-' for k in [0,1,3,4,6,7]), 'Bad permission format (read-write)'
    assert all(p[k] in 'xs-' for k in [2,5]), 'Bad permission format (execute)'
    assert p[8] in 'xt-', 'Bad permission format (execute other)'
    
    m = 0
    
    if p[0] == 'r': m |= stat.S_IRUSR 
    if p[1] == 'w': m |= stat.S_IWUSR 
    if p[2] == 'x': m |= stat.S_IXUSR 
    if p[2] == 's': m |= stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_ISUID 
    
    if p[3] == 'r': m |= stat.S_IRGRP 
    if p[4] == 'w': m |= stat.S_IWGRP 
    if p[5] == 'x': m |= stat.S_IXGRP 
    if p[5] == 's': m |= stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_ISGID 
    
    if p[6] == 'r': m |= stat.S_IROTH 
    if p[7] == 'w': m |= stat.S_IWOTH 
    if p[8] == 'x': m |= stat.S_IXOTH 
    if p[8] == 't': m |= stat.S_IXOTH | stat.S_ISVTX
    
    return m
```

Note that setting SUID/SGID/SVTX bits will automatically set the corresponding execute bit. Without this, the resulting permission would be invalid (`ST` characters).

Answer (score 6):

You can use, pathlib also

```
from pathlib import Path

fl = Path("file_name")

fl.chmod(0o444)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.4+, when working with `pathlib.Path` objects, you can call `chmod()` directly as a method on the path object. The following example is given in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.chmod):

```py
>>> p = Path('setup.py')
>>> p.stat().st_mode
33277
>>> p.chmod(0o444)
>>> p.stat().st_mode
33060
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to remember flags. Remember that you can always do:

`subprocess.call(["chmod", "a-w", "file/path])`

Not portable but easy to write and remember:

- u - user
- g - group
- o - other
- a - all
- + or - (add or remove permission)
- r - read
- w - write
- x - execute

Refer `man chmod` for additional options and more detailed explanation.

Comment: The key problem with this approach is that it _assumes_ that it's on a Unix-like system. This isn't portable because it wouldn't work on Windows. You should be using `os.chmod` as suggested in Gitano's answer.