# Errno 13 permission denied when writing file

Tags: python, linux, permissions

I have been trying to follow this post [Changing file permission in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249440/changing-file-permission-in-python) to change the permissions of the directory and folder being generated by my python code.  However I am still getting an error `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

```
absPath = createFolder + "/" + collectionInterval
print absPath
if not os.path.exists(absPath):
    os.system("sudo mkdir " + absPath)
    os.chmod(absPath, stat.S_IRWXO | stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRWXG)

scriptName = ipAddress.replace(".", "")

#create script file and save it in that location
#need to replace "name" with a distinguishable name
saveFile = absPath + "/" + scriptName + "_" + script["datasourceID"] + "_" + script["datapointID"] + ".py"
print saveFile
with open(saveFile, "w") as script_file:
    os.chmod(saveFile, stat.S_IRWXO | stat.S_IRWXU | stat.S_IRWXG)
    script_file.write(script)
```

Comment: You do `sudo mkdir` but you're not using `sudo` for the chmod.  Is it failing the chmod?

Comment: "/" dir not yours ! Try "/home/*username*/" inside. And script runner is not *root* . Only root can write root dir. Never give permission to root dir.

Comment: it fails on the with open(saveFile, "w") as script_file: line,

Comment: Did you view the directory to check the permissions?

Comment: @SDilmac I am doing a os.walk to get the full path of the directory.

Comment: does it work if you execute the program with `sudo python name_of_script`?

Comment: Try  change absPath = createFolder + "/" + collectionInterval to

 absPath = "/home/user_name/"+createFolder + "/" + collectionInterval