# Change executable option after python's unzipping

Tags: python-3.x, executable, zip

I have a small trouble with file option - executable, after using extractall.

This is my part of code:

```
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_local_folder+file, 'r')
archive.extractall(path_to_local_folder)
os.remove(path_to_local_folder+file)
```

In my zip archive I have a file, which should have an option - executable. Of course I can add operation "make file as executable", but I think it's not a good idea.

P.S. I use Mac OS and Python 3.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249440/changing-file-permission-in-python

Comment: Yes, I know about this point, but I want to make this file as executable after operation: "extractall"

Comment: `os.chmod(path_to_local_folder+file_name, stat.S_IXUSR)`?

Comment: unlike a tar archive; zip doesn't preserve file permissions (such as the executable bit). Though there could be extensions that allow you to store such information (check whether `unzip -Z` works in your case).