# Possible to save to_csv using Pandas (or other module) so that the csv is read-only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I am using Python and Pandas. I want the processed dataframe to be saved in a read-only csv file, such that people can open and look at it but can not modify and resave/overwrite the existing csv file?

I check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), it doesn't seem to have that option. Any work-around for this?

Comment: No, you cannot do this directly through Pandas when you write the data

Comment: The concept of "read-only" is operating system and user/file system level specific and isn't/shouldn't be a part of a data analysis library... Have you thought if you can just use some OS command/wrapper around it to modify the file permissions afterwards?

Comment: You can set the OS permissions on the file to read-only but a user can easily change it. Sounds like you need to store your data in a database, not a `csv` file. Then you can define users and grant permissions over who can change what.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249440/changing-file-permission-in-python/16249475See

Comment: Thanks everyone.