# How to make a file non-editable?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I am working on an idea. I need a bit help here, as I don't have in depth knowledge of python modules(I mean I don't know all the python modules). Take a look at the code

```
file = open('Data.txt', 'w')
a = input('Enter your name in format F|M|L: ')
file.write(a)
file.close()
```

The above code opens a file which writes my data to it. However I want to edit the document only through python and not through opening it from saved location. Shortly I want to disable editions done by opening the file in text-editors.

Comment: You can't really do this. You could make the permissions of the file read-only, but a user with sufficient privileges could change it. I think your only real option would be to encrypt the contents, so even if the file is opened it can't be read or changed meaningfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing file permission in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249440/changing-file-permission-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Windows, the most straightforward option is to make the file read-only when your script is done. And set the read-only flag to false while your script is running. There are some ways to modify file permissions using `pywin32` library, but it's complicated and hard to find good examples.

```
import os
from stat import S_IWRITE, S_IREAD

fname = 'test.txt'

# if file exists, reset read only to false (allow write)
if os.path.isfile(fname):    
    os.chmod(fname, S_IWRITE)

fid = open(fname, 'w')
fid.write('shoobie doobie')
fid.close()
```

It's already been pointed out in the comments, this technique won't stop a determined person from changing the read only attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If text-editor is all your concern, use 'wb'  instead of 'w'.
Use 'rb' to open those files too.