# python 3, NamedTemporaryFile, permission denied

Tags: python, mysql

I need to create a file using `NamedTemporaryFile` and download some data into it:

```
 f = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv', delete=False)
 s3.download_fileobj(bucket, f"{files_dir}/metadata/{table_name}.csv.gz", f)
```

After that I need to load data into mysql table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`
But I get an error:

```
File '/tmp/tmp00f3funu.csv' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

I suppose mysql root user doesn't have enough permissions to read temp file.
This temp file has permissions to read only for owner of this file.
What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

here you either need to run as SQL user, which might not be the best idea

or just change file permissions after file is created using `os.chmod`
see detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16249655/7453765